# Validating resource files at compile time for Java JARs

Tags: java, resources, compile-time

Is there any way to verify at compile time that a resource referenced in source code has been included in an output JAR?

I am creating a Java JAR file that contains several PNGs. I load them like this:

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(MyClass.class.getResource("/path/to/resource.png");
```

Currently I don't find out about missing resources until I get exceptions at run time. I don't want a static list of resources in my build script, I want the compiler to figure out which resources I'm using in the code and check that they exist.

Comment: That's not possible. That's just a String literal passed as an argument to a method.

Comment: There are tools like ProGuard which can do sophisticated class file analysis. Surely it is possible to do something similar for resources?

Comment: Not at compile time with javac though.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it seems a waste of time to find errors in paths only at run time.

Another thing is that after moving files, the resources might not be seen right away in .jar for some reason. I needed to do some magic before they became visible (rebuilding the project, recreating the jar).

The idea could be to generate a java class (e.g. ResourceManager) with constants based on the file system before compilation.

And then use them for accessing resources:

Something like:

ResourceManager.GET_CUSTOMER_SQL_PATH

What do you reckon?